# Android Activity doesn't stop service and location updates

Tags: android, service, android-gps

I am tracking the current location of user in MainActivity using google api client and update the marker of current location. In the service, I track the current location of user and store it to firebase realtime db.

In `MainActivity`, I stop the service using button, by disconnecting the api client as well as stopping the service.

As per similar questions, I have implemented ondestroy in my service. Still after the api client disconnects, service is running and storing the location to firebase.

How do I stop this service ?

Maps Activity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    process = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
    stoptrek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonService);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    process.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"processing...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,MapsActivity2.class);
            MapsActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            finishActivity(1);

        }
    });

    stoptrek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopTrackerService();
            stopService(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, TrackingService.class));
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS tracking disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            startTrackerService();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        startTrackerService();
    }
}


public void stopTrackerService()
{
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) MapsActivity.this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Disconnected api client",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"api client is already disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Service :

public class TrackingService extends Service {

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client;

private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();

public TrackingService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    buildNotification();
    loginToFirebase();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    stopSelf();
}

//Create the persistent notification//

private void buildNotification() {
    String stop = "stop";
    // Create the persistent notification
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracking_enabled_notif))
            .setOngoing(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        startForeground(1, builder.build());
    }
}

private void loginToFirebase() {

    String email = "xyz@sdl.com";//getString(R.string.test_email);
    String password = "xyz123";//getString(R.string.test_password);


    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Firebase authentication failed");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    request.setInterval(5000);

    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    final String path = "location";
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                if (location != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(TrackingService.this,"recently add to DB",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ref.child(uid).child(path).push().setValue(location);
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

I have maps activity where I disconnect from googleapiclient, but even after stopping location updates and service, location is pushed in database.

Please tell me how to stop the service completely.
Thanks

Comment: because You are not stopping backgorund service

Comment: How do I stop that ? I display a notification when service is running, When the service stops, the notificaton is not there. But I could see the toast of values being pushed into db.

Comment: wait let me post the code for stopping service

Comment: Yeah sure !Thanks.

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method checks, either the service is running or not. If the service is running then it will return true otherwise false.

**Check Running service:**

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> cls) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (activityManager != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (cls.getName().equals(runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Stop Running service:**

```
ActivityStackManager.getInstance().stopLocationService(TrackingService.this);
```

**How it works:**

```
if (isServiceRunning(this, TrackingService.class)) {
    ActivityStackManager.getInstance().stopLocationService(TrackingService.this);
}
```

> **Note:** Stop the service too where you want to disconnect Location updates, As I can see you are disconnecting locaiton update at
>   stopTrackerService() method

**e-g:**

```
  public void stopTrackerService()
    {

    if (isServiceRunning(this, TrackingService.class)) {
        ActivityStackManager.getInstance().stopLocationService(TrackingService.this);
    }

    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) MapsActivity.this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Disconnected api client",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     else
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"api client is already disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**ActivityStackManager**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class ActivityStackManager {

    private static final ActivityStackManager mActivityStack = new ActivityStackManager();

    private ActivityStackManager() {
    }

    public static ActivityStackManager getInstance() {
        return mActivityStack;
    }

    public void stopLocationService(Context context) {
        if (isServiceRunning(context, TrackingService.class)) {
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
            Log.e("StackManager", "TrackingServiceStop");
        }
    }

    public void startLocationService(Context context){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, TrackingService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yeah sure, implementing it.

Comment: I have android studio v <3.5 , I don't think ActivityStackManager works there, any alternative ?

Comment: Oh sorry I forget to add that class, It's a singleton class I wrote it for service.

Comment: kindly past the isServiceRunning in ActivityStackManager... I have just pickup piece of code from my project that's why some it's missing

Comment: It is still pushing to the database. Also i couldn't see the log message you have printed in activity stack manager in my logcat

Comment: I don't think so, It working fine! It's mean your service is still running if it updates location updates. try to check again. may be you have made a minior mistake

Comment: The logcat dsiplayed service stopped, but location is still being pushed into db ? That means the code in service is getting executed, how is this so ?

Comment: public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "OnDestroy()");
        if (isServiceRunning(this, TrackingService.class)) {
            ActivityStackManager.getInstance().stopLocationService(LocationService.this);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

Comment: Try this method in in your services at place of stopItself.

Comment: Hey thanks, your code is perfect for stopping the service. But earlier I was  using stopService which  does the same. The problem was in onDestroy , I added the code (client.removelocationupdates(callback) in that and later stopSelf() . And that worked. The fault was not removing the location update provider.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer helped you! Good luck